# Get correct path for sparkdid.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path in AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, amazon-emr, spark-cassandra-connector, datastax-astra

I checked the entire web. but could not found the solution.

I am trying to connect astra cassandra using bundle in AWS EMR its able to download the bundle file but not loading it.

`spark.conf.set("sparkdid.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path", "secure-connect-app.zip")`

this is how I am giving path I know this is wrong path since its not loading the correct config returning connection refused with localhost.

I don't what is the correct path in EMR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connecting-using-an-astra-cloud-bundle-or-driver-profile-file-since-scc-25), then you see that the file could be either specified as URL of file on S3, or you can use —files option when submitting with spark-submit or spark-shell , then it will be available as just a file name, like you’re doing